# Remove php 5.3.29 from my system

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3, php-5.6

Previously I have both `PHP 5.6` and `PHP7` installed in my pc and switch between them every time I need for a web-app with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php[version]
```

But I made the error to install 5.3 because I one app I wanted to test was running with that PHP.

But now, no matter what I do, everytime I run php -v I always get:

> PHP 5.3.29 (cli)

I don't know where it's installed, I tried with locate php5.3 but I don't get anything (?) and with locate php5 I get all my installations from 5.6 and 7 that I want to activate.

I tried with `php --ini` to get a clue where is located but then:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

In `/usr/local/lib` there's nothing about php (?)

Any help with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked at askubuntu or superuser, it is not a programming question.

Comment: `which php` will tell you where the shell is finding php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it was only named as "php", so I couldn' track it down with the version number.

Then it was simply as

```
sudo apt-get purge php
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
sudo apt-get purge php5*
```

or use [brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew remove php-{old version}
brew unlink php {old verion}
brew link {new version}
```